# Laptop fan speed with strange behaviour

Tags: laptop, fan, asus-laptop, speedfan

I have had a N550JV Asus laptop for more than 6 years. Recently I noticed the fan speed noise increase without any reason, the CPU activity is normal and the system has been checked for any probable virus.

I then used SpeedFan software, here I attach the chart. Could anyone help me with this weird situation?

[image: SpeedFan chart]

Comment: I edited in your picture. Is it similar to the issue described here? If so  you could try disconnecting and reconnecting the battery. https://forums.tomsguide.com/threads/asus-fx502vml-fans-keep-turning-full-power-then-suddenly-off.428846/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I checked :)